# Can't install Limbo update 1.2-1

Tags: installation

Yesterday an update was released for the Humble Indie Bundle game Limbo.

I have previously installed Limbo through the Software Center. But when I try installing the new version I get the following:

```
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 189895 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ia32-limbo (from .../ia32-limbo_1.2-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /home/carroarmato0/Applications/Games/Humble Bundle/ia32-limbo_1.2-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/limbo/lib/python/distversion.py', which is also in package limbo-bin:i386 1.0-0ubuntu4
dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb (subprocess): failed in write on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy: Broken pipe
```

Comment: Did you uninstall the old version first? (Possibly you should.)

Comment: I did, but I also had to remove the special repository the Software Center added for Limbo. Removed that too. But long story short, the new update doesn't work at all for me. I'm kinda hoping that the update would come through the Software Center itself and do the update properly.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. Search for and remove any limbo's related section.
Then

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If everything flows with no errors, try to reinstall limbo.